# How to restart explorer without losing open windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch, path, files-folders

When I have to restart `explorer.exe`, usually I have many folders open, which get closed in the process. So is there a way to reopen these folders automatically after restarting explorer?

Comment: There is a PowerShell module that does exactly this as an answer to this duplicate question: https://superuser.com/a/1770244/216046

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `batch` script:

1. Makes a list of currently opened windows → saves it to a `txt` file
2. Restarts windows `explorer.exe`
3. Re-opens folders from the `txt` list → deletes `txt` file

---

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

powershell  @^(^(New-Object -com shell.application^).Windows^(^)^).Document.Folder.Self.Path >> prevfolderpaths.txt

taskkill /im explorer.exe /f

start explorer.exe

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN (prevfolderpaths.txt) DO (

set "var=%%f"
set "firstletters=!var:~0,2!"

IF "!firstletters!" == "::" ( start /min shell:%%~f ) ELSE ( start /min "" "%%~f" )

)

del "prevfolderpaths.txt"
```

---

Once you save the code as `restart_explorer.bat` .. next you should

1. **Right Click** → Sent to → Desktop (create shortcut)
2. **Right Click** shortcut → **Run:** Minimized → and [add your shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1lSy.png)

Comment: In **Folder Options** there is a checkbox called **Restore previous folder windows at logon** and this restores them whenever you restart or signout or whatever. There is a way to get this done with batch alone, and not depend on powershell, but it's a lot more complicated and not convenient. However I don't know whether it's possible to save whether windows were fullscreen, or minimized or windowed... so this script justs opens the windows minimized.

Comment: Can you convert this to powershell script?

Answer (score 2):

> so this script justs opens the windows minimized

I can't comment yet but would like to improve goldnick7's answer. You can keep your folders maximized by deleting second `/min`:

```
IF "!firstletters!" == "::" ( start /min shell:%%~f ) ELSE ( start "" "%%~f" )"
```

I left first `/min` there to remember this flag exists.

---

Also, in multi-user environment you can use this command to affect only your processes:

```
taskkill /f /fi "UserName eq %UserName%" /im explorer.exe
```

It is important that `/fi` goes before `/im`, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell $open_folders = @((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder.Self.Path; Stop-Process -Name explorer -Force;  foreach ($element in $open_folders){Invoke-Item $($element)}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This appears to be a reply to the request above "Can you convert this to powershell script?". It's a one-liner that restarts Explorer with the same windows open as before.