# How to open pinned File Explorer to a quick access location, with the quick access path shown in the path bar?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I have File Explorer pinned to my taskbar and it opens to Home.
I'd like it to open to my Downloads directory instead.

As far as I know, there is no option or preference to change the initial location in File Explorer.  If there is, please let me know in an answer.

My attempted workaround was to create a desktop shortcut for explorer.exe with command line arguments:
%SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe %UserProfile%\Downloads

This works, there is a problem (1) and a slight annoyance (2).

1. After opening the shortcut and pinning the resulting window to the taskbar, the arguments are lost.  The pinned shortcut is just a default File Explorer shortcut.
2. The full path is displayed in the path bar. When I click on a quick access location in File Explorer, it is displayed as a quick access path. Is there a command line argument that opens File Explorer to a quick access path displayed in the path bar? [image: Paths in path bar]

Comment: In Win10, Quick Access shortcuts to user's system folders would "jump" to their `This PC` path. Has that changed?

Comment: It is possible to pin a working shortcut if you create a shortcut directly for `explorer.exe` and then choose "Pin to taskbar" in RMB menu, but then the icon isn't functional and explorer opens as separate entry on toolbar - not sure if this helps you.

Comment: See if you can save and restore the folder with the module I linked ot in this answer: 
 https://superuser.com/a/1770244/881098 . I think someone who tested it said it worked for Win11 as well....